# Usar Vetor no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Olá mestres do JavaScript, estou estudando vetores, tenho o seguinte código, o arquivo .js:

```
var indice, qtd_Veiculos, tot_Veiculos, nome_veiculo = new Array(400);
```

para o arquivo index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Aprendendo Algoritmos com JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="scripts/aplicativo_020.js"></script>   
    <script>
        qtd_Veiculos = parseInt(prompt("Digite a Quantidade de Veículos para Cadastrar ou -1 Para Sair:"));
        while (qtd_Veiculos != -1)
        {
            for (indice = 1; indice <= qtd_Veiculos; indice++)
            {               
                nome_veiculo[indice] = (prompt("Digite o Nome do Veículo:"));
                tot_Veiculos = (indice + 1);
            }
            qtd_Veiculos = parseInt(prompt("Digite a Quantidade de Veículos para Cadastrar ou -1 Para Sair:"));
        }
        tot_Veiculos = (tot_Veiculos -1);
        for (indice = 1; indice <= qtd_Veiculos; indice++)      
        {
            document.write("O Veículo " + nome_veiculo[indice] + " tem o índice " + indice);            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Não sei onde estou errando, pois não estou conseguindo exibir os dados do vetor. No aguardo de uma simples ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando `qtd_Veiculos` ao invés de `tot_Veiculos` no `for`que é usado na hora de imprimir, abaixo tem o código de como deveria ficar.

```
for (indice = 1; indice <= tot_Veiculos; indice++)      
{
   document.write("O Veículo " + nome_veiculo[indice] + " tem o índice " + indice);            
}
```

Comment: André, muito grato. Não percebi este erro.